# Efeito Slidedown com menus li

Tags: jquery, css

Estou tentando criar um efeito usando `css` e `jquery` para um menu onde o mesmo tera o efeito de "slidedown" quando clicado em um determinado link, porém mesmo que eu coloque a lista dentro de uma `div` com `height: 0` ela continua aparecendo.

Já tentei colocar `overflow: auto` `hidden` na `ul` e na `li` porém sem sucesso.

```
$('.open-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```js
$('.open-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 0;
}

.box ul li {
  overflow: auto;
}

.open {
  animation: open-menu .7s linear;
}

@keyframes open-menu {
  from { height: 0; }
  to { height: 200px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="open-link">Abrir</button>
```

Gostaria de saber também como posso efetuar a animação e não "zera-la" e sim manter o estado final após a animação.

Comment: Não use stacksnippets (trecho de código) sem necessidade, eles não são pra formatar e sim pra executar códigos js+css+html que façam alguma coisa, se não for pra fazer nada use a marcação normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que não é preciso a animation nos css. Podes fazer assim:

```js
$('.open-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all .7s linear;
}
.box ul li {
  overflow: auto;
}

.open {
  max-height: 500px; /* ajustar aqui para uma altura que saibas que nunca há de chegar */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="open-link">Abrir</button>
```

Lembro-te também que podes fazer só com jQuery:

```js
$('.open-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.box').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>World</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button class="open-link">Abrir</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou Miguel, obrigado, notei que realmente não precisava do `keyframes` mas creio que o meu erro era não ter colocado o `overflow` na propria `box`

Comment: De nada @RafaelAcioly, ainda bem que resultou. Realmente não era preciso7